# Round off floating point values in dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am struggling to round off floating values in dictionary. To generate the dictionary I have used:

```
[{i: x.count(i)/float(len(x)) for i in x} for x in l]
```

My dictionary is:

```
P = [{'A': 0.700000000, 'B': 0.255555555}, {'B': 0.55555555, 'C': 0.55555555}, {'A': 0.255555555, 'B': 0.210000000, 'C': 0.2400000000}]
```

I need:

```
P = [{'A': 0.70, 'B': 0.25}, {'B': 0.55, 'C': 0.55}, {'A': 0.25, 'B': 0.21, 'C': 0.24}]
```

Comment: Have you considered using `round`? There are plenty of Qs and As about rounding floats already, why do you think *"in dict"* makes it any different? Also, why have you tagged with two different versions - which are you actually using?

Answer (score 14):

This is a fairly simple way to do it. However, .7000 will become just .7

**Rounding**

```
for dict_value in P:
        for k, v in dict_value.items():
            dict_value[k] = round(v, 2)

[{'A': 0.7, 'B': 0.26}, {'C': 0.56, 'B': 0.56}, {'A': 0.26, 'C': 0.24, 'B': 0.21}]
```

**Truncating**

```
for dict_value in P:
    for k, v in dict_value.items():
        dict_value[k] = float(str(v)[:4])
[{'A': 0.7, 'B': 0.25}, {'C': 0.55, 'B': 0.55}, {'A': 0.25, 'C': 0.24, 'B': 0.21}]
```

The conversion to string chops off the extra 0's in `0.700000` and that is why it still shows as `0.7` instead of `0.70`.

Comment: And you get `0.56` rather than `0.55`

Comment: This is rounding, not really cutting off the extra digits. If that is what you wanted you would need to modify the code a bit to do that.

Comment: I know; note that I am not the OP.

Comment: Oops. Didn't even look :)

Comment: In OP's data-set `float(str(v)[:4])` is working, but in general it's will fail for values greater than 10. you can use `v = (int(v*100))/100.0`, to truncate extra digits.

Answer (score 1):

We can sacrifice some readability for succinctness:

```
[{k: round(v, 2) for k, v in dct.items()} for dct in P]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert it to a df and then round it up:

```
pd.DataFrame([dct]).round(2)
```